# Writing an "if-then" formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want a formula that answers `if x <= y then "a"` but `if x <= z then "b"` but `if > z then "0"`

I've tried several things, this is the closest I've come to solving:

```
=IF(A36>8,0,IF(A36<=8,"1 Case",IF(A36<=4,"2 Cases")))
```

anything less than 8 always gives me the 1 case answer.

Comment: you need to check `<=4` before `<=8`. What `several things`did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the smaller value first then.
Try this:

```
=IF(A2>8,0,IF(A2<=4,"2 Case",IF(A2<=8,"1 Case")))
```

Hope this helps.